# OpenTok Ionic 3 - publisher.cycleVideo function not found

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins, opentok

I am using the ionic opentok plugin from this repo,
https://github.com/opentok/cordova-plugin-opentok
I have, of course, followed the https://github.com/opentok/opentok-cordova-samples projects and built an app. However, I am struggling with switching the camera in an ongoing video session.
My code is simple, a button on the screen,

```
<div class="controls-btn-inner-icon" (click)="toggleCamera()">
    <ion-icon ios="md-camera" md="md-camera"></ion-icon>
</div>
```

and the method,

```
toggleCamera() {
    this.publisher.cycleVideo();
}
```

It gives me the error, on the Debug console,

```
TypeError: this.publisher.cycleVideo is not a function
        [[StableObjectId]]:3
        message:"this.publisher.cycleVideo is not a function"
        ngDebugContext:DebugContext_ {view: Object, nodeIndex: 106, nodeDef: Object, …}
        ngErrorLogger:function () { … }
        stack:"TypeError: this.publisher.cycleVideo is not a function\n    at 
    VideoSessionPage.webpackJsonp.92.VideoSessionPage.toggleCamera (http://localhost:8080/build/main.js:936:24)\n    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (ng:///AppModule/VideoSessionPage.ngfactory.js:247:31)\n    at handleEvent (http://localhost:8080/build/vendor.js:14275:155)\n    at callWithDebugContext (http://localhost:8080/build/vendor.js:15784:42)\n    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (http://localhost:8080/build/vendor.js:15371:12)\n    at dispatchEvent (http://localhost:8080/build/vendor.js:10690:25)\n    at http://localhost:8080/build/vendor.js:11315:38\n    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/build/vendor.js:40626:53)\n    at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8080/build/polyfills.js:3:15660)\n    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:8080/build/vendor.js:5437:33)"
    __proto__:Error {constructor: , name: "TypeError", message: "", …}
```

`

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you tell me what settings did you do in order to publish videos from an iphone ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

The `cycleVideo` method is only available using the [OpenTok JS SDK](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/). To toggle the camera when using the [Cordova OpenTok Plugin](https://github.com/opentok/cordova-plugin-opentok), please use the following method:
`publisher.setCameraPosition('front');` or `publisher.setCameraPosition('back')`;

Using the plugin, you can also initialize the [Publisher](https://github.com/opentok/cordova-plugin-opentok/blob/master/docs/publisher.md) object with either the **front** or the **back** camera using the `cameraName` property as part of the properties argument for the [`initPublisher`](https://github.com/opentok/cordova-plugin-opentok/blob/master/docs/ot.md#initPublisher) method like so:

```
const publisherProperties = {
  cameraName: 'front',
};
const publisher = OT.initPublisher(publisherProperties);
```